# OpenCv - Get the a specific HUE value from a hue histogram

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, tracking

I have a hue histogram with 32 bins. Then, on this histogram i found the bin where the the maximum value is reach.

Here the function:

```
    int getHref(cv::Mat& hist){
    double min=0,max=0;
    Point minLoc,maxLoc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(hist, &min, &max, &minLoc,&maxLoc,noArray());
    return maxLoc.y;
    }
```

Now i have a bin but how can i get the value of hue which belong to this bin ?

Actually,i would like to get hue reference Href which is the hue value which has the highest
frequency in the hue histogram but i'm a bit confused.

My final purspose if to compute the hue distance histogram for object tracking.

Thank you

Comment: 180/32 * binNr up to 180/32 * (binNr+1) is the value range covered by that bin (binNr). This Hue value is a OpenCV hue val which must be multiplied by 2 to get the "normal" 360 degree hue range.